# How to write one to one LINQ Query

Tags: vb.net, linq, vb.net-2010

I am a beginner and learning LINQ in VB.Net. I have one **table A** with column

**workID (PK)** and **idAccount**.

And another **table B** with column

**Bid(PK), BName and workID(FK)** .

There is **one to one relationship** between **table A and table B**.

Now I want to put/copy both the table data to another **table C** which has column as

**workID, idAccount, BName**. But I don't know how to write a LINQ query and get both table data and put it in 3rd table. Please help me. I have tried below till now. Below is the code snippet of my project.

```
Public Function Hello(ByVal dt As A, ByVal dtm As B) 
                Dim dtReturn As New C
                If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Any Then
                  Dim row As WorkOrderRow `row corresponding to the C Table
                    For Each r In dt
                        row = dtReturn.NewWorkRow 'traversing the row 
                        With row
                            .WorkID = r.WorkID
                            .idAccount = r.idAccount
                        End With
                        dtReturn.AddWorkOrderActivityRow(row)
                    Next
                End If
        End Function
```

its working totally fine but I need to put the data of **B** too. With above code I am able to copy only data of table A. Kindly guide me how should I write my LINQ query and traverse it.

I should be able to do something like

```
                     With row
                        .WorkID = x.WorkID
                        .idAccount = x.idAccount
                        .BName = x.BName
                    End With
```

x being the row generated by the query.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would like to join the result of A and B first (sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), then create rows of C. This is much easier.

```
        Dim newCs = (From a In tableA
                 Join b In tableB On a.workID Equals b.workID
                 Select New TableC With {
                        .workID = a.workID,
                        .idAccount = a.idAccount,
                        .BName = b.BName
                     })
```

Comment: I am new to LINQ. Can you elaborate with one example for one to one LINQ and copying it to another third table. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: added a sample for you :) but please also read the link to get more details (e.g. handling left joins). The link is in C# but syntax of linq are very similar between C# and vb.net

Comment: _but syntax of linq are very similar between C# and vb.net_ - no it is not :)